# Hive Windowing functions - current row and unbounded following

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, window-functions

What is the difference between unbounded preceding and current row to unbounded preceding and unbounded following.

Suppose I am writing a code:

```
from groceries
select id, revenue, day, sum(revenue)
over ( order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

and I am writing another:

```
from groceries
select id, revenue, day, sum(revenue)
over ( order by id rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```

what will the difference in the execution of the code?

Comment: You can run `explain <query>;` to see the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

First sum

```
sum(revenue)
over ( order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

is a running sum: the dataset is ordered by id and for each row the sum is calculated for the frame `[first row...current row]`. So, for each row the frame is different and increases with each next row. The last row, which corresponds to the max id will have total sum (sum of all rows).

Second sum  `( order by id rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)` - is a total sum of all rows - the frame is the same for each row [first row ... last row]. Ordering makes no any sense here and your second expression is equivalent of `sum(revenue) over ()` as you can see, it produces the same result:

```
with mydata as (
select 1 id, 10 revenue union all
select 2 id, 10 revenue union all
select 3 id, 10 revenue union all
select 4 id, 10 revenue union all
select 5 id, 10 revenue
)

select id, revenue, 
       sum(revenue) over ( order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row) sum1,
       sum(revenue) over ( order by id rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) sum2,
       sum(revenue) over() sum3 --this is the same as sum2
  from mydata
  order by id
```

Result:

```
id  revenue sum1    sum2    sum3
1   10      10      50      50
2   10      20      50      50
3   10      30      50      50
4   10      40      50      50
5   10      50      50      50
```